# serverless vs serverfull in express-graphql?

Tags: node.js, graphql, express-graphql

I am introducing my self to serverless and stumbled upon this: https://github.com/serverless-components/express and can't seem to understand what's difference with serverfull deployed to heroku? see i have this code in serverless:

```
app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlHTTP(async (request) => {
    // add user context
    console.log("test");
    return {
      schema,
      graphiql: true,
      context: {
        request,
        //user
      },
    };
  })
);

module.exports = app;
```

and serverfull:

```
app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlHTTP(async (request) => {
    // add user context
    return {
      schema,
      graphiql: true,
      context: {
        request,
      },
    };
  })
);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

can somebody tell me if there's an advantage using serverless in express-graphql? my frontend stack is graphql-relay and i am used to express-graphql and want to explore serverless using express-graphql stack but can't seem to find a good resource to do it. as i am reading from [this](https://css-tricks.com/building-serverless-graphql-api-in-node-with-express-and-netlify/):

> At this point, I think it’s worth noting that not everyone agrees that
> running Express in a serverless function is a good idea. As Paul
> Johnston explains, if you’re building your functions for scale, it’s
> best to break each piece of functionality out into its own
> single-purpose function. Using Express the way I have means that every
> time a request goes to the API, the whole Express server has to be
> booted up from scratch — not very efficient. Deploy to production at
> your own risk.

please clarify me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the benefits of serverless: you execute your code on-demand only when it's needed in contrast to the traditional servers that will be running 24/7.
In addition, it also managed by a service provider so you won't need to worry about maintaining and scaling your server.

You can read more

https://dashbird.io/blog/business-benefits-of-serverless

https://www.serverless.com/blog/running-scalable-reliable-graphql-endpoint-with-serverless

https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/

https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-architecture-code-patterns/